# MVC View Loading DIV but javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I can not figure this out.

I have a Controller that loads my main.php:

```
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>$('#container').load('index.php?path=wizard&wizard_id=<?php echo $_GET['wizard_id']; ?> #wizard');</script>
```

"index.php?path=wizard&wizard_id=1" loads: view/module/wizard.php'
 view/module/wizard.php looks like this:

```
 <div id="wizard" data-wizard_id="<?php echo $groups_in_set['wizard_id']; ?>" data-total_sets="<?php echo $groups_in_set['total_sets']; ?>">
        <div id="set" name="<?php echo $groups_in_set['wand_set']; ?>">                 
            <?php foreach ($groups_in_set['groups'] as $group){ ?>
                <!--Step Text -->
                <h1><?php echo $group['group']; ?></h1>
                <!--Step Detail -->
                <div data-group="<?php echo $group['group']; ?>">   
                <script>alert("group");</script> // No script tags pass to main.php     
                    <?php foreach($group['wands'] as $wand){ ?>                 
                        <span id="prompt_elements_<?php echo $wand->wand_id; ?>"></span>
                        <script>                    
                            // Load Wand
                            // Script not executing on ajax load
                            loadPromptElements('<?php echo $wand->prompt_type; ?>', <?php echo $wand->wand_id; ?>);
                        </script>
                    <?php } // End Wand Loop ?>
                </div> <!-- End Group -->                               
            <?php } // End Group Loop ?>
        </div> <!-- End Set -->
    </div>  <!-- End Wizard -->
```

As you can see from my comments everything loads correctly except the "loadPromptElements" function. The entire script tag does not display in my rendered HTML. I can not figure this one out and need some help. Thanks community!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding jQuery** `.load()` **handling of scripts**:

> If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL *[like #wizard]*, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are **not executed**.

### [jQuery Reference Page](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution)

```
$('#container').load('index.php?...stuff... #wizard');  // <--- THAT
```

So you have a couple of options.  Either find another way around using the `#wizard` selector after the URL in your `.load()` call **or** you can put it all (that one function) into a separate JS file and load it at the same time with `.getScript()`.  You'll probably have to make it a PHP file so you can utilize the `foreach()` loop and whatnot.